# Build image using makefile

Tags: linux, android-source

recently I saw that AOSP project uses Android.mk files which create image files as Target. For example ramdisk.img using make file

However, I do not understand how these images are built.
Is it possible to create image for any Unix systems program using makefile?

Comment: Of course.  Linux itself is built with a Makefile (well, a whole bunch of Makefiles).  Make just facilitates the other tools.

Comment: Makefile describes how `make` is going to invoke other tools

Comment: A make file can run arbitrary commands. So for example to build an image it could use dd to create an empty file, mkfs to format it, mount, cp and unmount. This is only one way...